# Sybase IQ Pagination

Tags: t-sql, sap-iq

I wonder if anyone has a solution to the following requirement.  I have a stored procedure which returns a result set of for example 1000 rows.  Now I need to limit this to 100 rows at a time.  So I will pass in a start and end index value and I only want the records between the start index rowcount and the end index rowcount

So for example my stored procedure call signature looks like this:-

```
stp_mystoredproc(startIndex INTEGER, endIndex INTEGER)
```

So if I set `startIndex = 100` and `endIndex = 200` then I want the stored procedure to return the records in rows 100 to 200 out of the total reset set of 1000.

My first attempt is put the result set in a temp table with an identity column then select based on the identity the range I need but this is somewhat slow.  I know Oracle supports pagination so you can page through your result set.  Anyone know if Sybase IQ (v12.6 or v12.7) supports something similar?

The end goal is to page through the entire result set (1000 records) but in 100 row pages at a time.

Comment: After a bit of searching I found Sybase IQ has two features which help with pagination.  The function NUMBER(*) gives you a running count of records in the result set and ROWID provides the Row Id from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know sybase. But maybe you could do something like this

```
myproc(@count int, @lastid int)

select top @count *
from MyTabel 
where id > @lastid 
order by id
```

first call

```
exec myproc(100, 0)
```

gives you something like

```
3 appels
4 banana
..
..
..
346 potatto
```

next call

`exec myproc myproc(100,346)`

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a nice idea and should work just fine.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase IQ and Sybase SQL Anywhere share the same query execution engine and (mostly) SQL syntax, so you can generally use SQL Anywhere syntax. Try this:

```
select top (endIndex-startIndex) start at startIndex from <query>
```

I'm not sure if you can use an expression in the `top` clause, so you may have to create a string and use `execute immediate`.

See http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/select-statement.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried it on Sybase IQ v12.7 but it does not seem to be supported.  I will try it again under v15 in a few weeks and see if it works there.