# Sybase IQ - Cursor with Java

Tags: java, database, pagination, cursor, sap-iq

I need to fetch around 1 Billion records and process them in Java.

It might not be possible to fetch all in single select statement. How can I do pagination or can I use cursors?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028521/sybase-iq-pagination) solution provides stored proc as answer. Is that the only option, if this works?

Comment: Do you really need to do this logic inside the Java application? I'm asking because store procedures are very slow in IQ as well as network time compared to doing aggregation direct on IQ is really high.

Comment: I need to process each record in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to score here:

1) Use a cursor:
Sybase IQ is supporting cursor feature. Check the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315719.htm) on how to do so (I've linked 15.1 into as it was the first I found and you did not mentioned which version you are running on. Should be the same on 16). As you didn't provide much details I will not write any pseudo code which is already printed in documentation.

2) Split your query up into logical parts and build up your pagination on your on. So fetch all rows for a year before handling them in Java.

Of course, combining 1 and 2 will work.

Again: IQ is most likely much faster doing the logic direct inside the database as your Java-tool ever will be.